# What is a data stucture to store this type of data

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, collections, dictionary

For example I have four spreadsheets and I want to store something like this:

```
Rows 1,2,3 from spread1, 
Rows 1,2 from spread2,  
Rows 3,4 from spread3, 
Row 3 from spread4
```

I thought I should use a Dictionary<> but MSDN says the Key Should be uniqe.
so what is a correct way of doing this?

P.S: I am using .NET 3.5, cannot use Tuple.
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to handle ranges as well? i.e. Rows 1 through 56, without having to list all 56 row numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom class and use that as your key. Include all the fields you need to create a unique key (spreadsheet name and list of rows) then override Equals and GetHashCode appropriately.

Comment: is there any way of creating a Collection of Collections for this? rather than a new class...current code is using it a global variable all over the code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a list of lists to me, `List<List<T>>`. It would probably be nice to wrap it in a custom class to give you the semantics you want (if not, it can get complicated to remember what's in which list, etc; and perhaps you want some additional metadata on each sublist).

Comment: can you please show me a sample code from declaration of this list of list?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and straigtforward solution:

```
IDictionary<string, IList<int>> map = new Dictionary<string, IList<int>>
{
   { "spread1", new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 } },
   { "spread2", new List<int> { 1, 2 } },
   { "spread3", new List<int> { 3, 4 } },
   { "spread5", new List<int> { 3 } }
}
```

If you need some kind of flexibility - abstract spreads and related rows by a custom classes like suggested by others.

Comment: looks like what I need. but still a confsuion for me is that here you are hard coding 1,2,3...but in real code for example this is inside a method call and each time this method is called we add one of those values, for example we add value 2 to spread1 dictionary...next time we add value 4 to spread3 dictionary...but here in sample code we are using NEW, so how can still keep the previous value and add to them?